# OR operator for postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I treat the test result as pass either field A is "A" or field B is "B". How can i achieve that in postman?

I tried

```
(pm.expect(responseJson.output.generic[0].fieldA).to.eql(pm.iterationData.get("A"))||pm.expect(responseJson.output.generic[0].fieldB).to.eql(pm.iterationData.get("B")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

`pm.expect(cond1 || cond2).to.be.true;`

In your case, I think that would be something like

```
pm.expect(
    responseJson.output.generic[0].fieldA === pm.iterationData.get("A") || 
    responseJson.output.generic[0].fieldB === pm.iterationData.get("B")
  ).to.be.true;
```